# How to pass a closure in performSegue's sender parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, modal-dialog, closures, segue

In my **iOS** App, I would like to ask the user a question and then take some actions depending on the answer.

In many other programming frameworks I would have used a modal dialog that waits for the user to enter the result and then returns that result to the main code. But, to my knowledge, the UIKit framework does not contain such *modal dialogs* . Instead I use a modal *segue*, but since the call to `performSegue` returns immediately the programming becomes somewhat messy...

The `performSegue` has a sender parameter of kind `Any?`. Can I use that parameter to pass a *closure* with the code to be executed when the user exits the segue? And, if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing this question has three down votes! I can't see why. In my opinion my question is clearly stated.

It is possible to use `performSegue` and `prepare(for:sender:)`. But using `instantiateViewController` requires less setup work.

Here is a solution *based on Yasser's answer*:

In storyboard I created a *view controller* (`PawnPromotionVC`) with a semi transparent white background view,  and a non transparent smaller sub view containing the "dialog". The view controller has a `onExit` attribute declared as follows:

```
   var onExit : ((Piece) -> Void)?
```

Below is the action handler for button tapps in that view controller (by the way, the objective of the "dialog" is to asks the user what chess piece a pawn should be promoted to):

```
  @IBAction func pieceButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let piece = Piece(rawValue: sender.tag)!

        if let run = onExit {
            run( piece )
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

To launch the dialog I call

```
  if ... {
      runPawnPromotionDialog(){
          (piece:Piece) in
           print("the pawn should be promoted to a \(piece)" )
           ...
           ...
      }
  }
```

from my *mainViewController*. The function `runPawnPromotionDialog`, also implemented in the mainViewController, is almost implemented as suggested by Yasser:

```
  func runPawnPromotionDialog( onExit: @escaping (Piece) -> Void ){

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PawnPromotionVC") as! PawnPromotionVC

        vc.definesPresentationContext = true
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
        vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve

        vc.onExit = onExit
        self.present(vc,animated: false,completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible with `performSegue` but you could use `prepareForSegue` to send values when the segue is performed.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {        
    let vc = segue.destination as! MyViewController
    vc.myParameter = myValue

}
```

but if you just want to give the user a dialog and wait for the answer there's another way to do that.

you could make a viewController with default background which will make it hidden and then add a View inside it and customize it however you want, you can consider it as an Alert. and then initiate it when you want to ask the user for the data.

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "alert") as! AlertViewController
vc.definesPresentationContext = true
vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.overCurrentContext
//Here you can pass data into the viewController you're initiating
vc.myParameter = myValue
self.present(vc,animated: false,completion: nil)
```

this way the UIView you customized in the viewController will appear just like a normal alert over the current viewController.

Comment: Thank you for both answers! My plans is (was?) to to add the following in prepare for segue:  if let closure = sender as? () -> { vc.closure = closure }, and then let the vc call closure() on exit.  In your second answer, do you mean that I should submit the closure as the completion handler to present? Or do you mean that the call to present will behave like a dialog and not return until the user exits it?

Comment: using the closure inside the viewController you'll be initiating would be better, you could try using it in the present completion handler but I'm not sure if that would work or not. I didn't test it with a closure before.